# Gantt diagram alternative: cards instead of tasks, one guy per task

Tags: tasks, gantt, task-management

Is there an alternative to the Gantt diagram, which differs in the following way.

1. From top to bottom employees are listed, not tasks. The task is presented as a rectangle on an employee's 'timeline'.
2. The task can be assigned to a single person only, not multiple 'resources'.

It could look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Why (I guess) a tool based on the diagram can be useful. I'm working with several contractors and I'd like to make notes about what every person is doing right now and share this information with all who is interested. It would be ideal if I could also create a task card with its left border showing creation date and its right border showing the supposed completion date then the current date and finally the date when the task is actually closed/done. When only undone tasks are visible ('Show completed tasks' is off), I would control that all contractors are busy (have a task) and no task is prolonged too much. When the completed tasks are shown, I would be able to see what a person has done for the project, how much time every his/her task took, what is the typical time window between tasks and so on.

When Gantt or Kanban is used, the focus is on **tasks**. My focus is on **people**. I want them to have at least a task (if not, I would investigate what's wrong with their input) and do the tasks as soon as they can (if the task is too wide on the diagram and still not closed I would investigate what's wrong with the task or maybe with the doer).

**UPDATE 2**

The question is about the name of the diagram. Say, Kanban, modern Kanban, UML sequence and so on. It's not about software recommendation. Management techniques and tips like using calendar applications (a software program class, not a specific application) are also welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Please add more detail.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Gantt diagrams are good for planning but not so good for tracking current activities by resource.  For tracking current activities, what you have looks like a variant on a Kanban board.

Comment: @BillThor Yes, Kanban is the most similar thing I've found so far, but since I saw "just in time" I thought it unlikely fits. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: @noober welcome to PMSE. Software recommendations are off-topic here. You can try to ask your question at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I use a Gantt diagram for this, with each task being one person's assignment. So if John and Jane are working together on the same task, I create two tasks on the chart: one for John and one for Jane. I sometimes take this further, so that I allocate each person by month so if John is testing in January and February, I create two tasks for John, and so on. Does this help?

Comment: @SergeyKudryavtsev The question is not about software recommendation, it's about diagram type. Which is, yes, needed for software search, but it's another question.

Comment: @Iain9688 On the Gantt diagram even if you have only one persons tasks, they will be arranged not just from left to right (along the timeline) but also from top to bottom (every task on a new line). If you add other guys, it would be even worse, because the tasks will be mixed up.

Comment: @noober If so, can you re-formulate this phrase _"I'm looking for a software program or a web-service, implementing something similar"_ in your question? It's a little bit confusing.

Comment: @SergeyKudryavtsev It's been deleted.

Comment: @noober Yes, I have already seen your edit. I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a shared calendaring application for this kind of tracking.  The level of detail you have is similar to the kind of detail I use to track vacations.

Create each assignment as a multiple day all day event.  The title could be something like "John: Task 1".  You can add details in the notes section.

Alternatively you can create a calendar per person and show them in a single view.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why the calendars are better than Gantt. The approach has the same issues: unwanted line breaks (in this case not after every task, but at the end of every week), different person tasks mixed up on the shared calendar/diagram, if you use a calendar/diagram per person you cannot compare anymore.

Comment: I use version one - https://www.versionone.com/    I am not sure what king of project management you are using but it sounds agile.  I allow people to take their own tasks in line with the principles of agile and allocate any remaining ones out.  It is a very good piece of software and there are some others available.